# Yammer JS SDK webpack jsonp namespace collision

Tags: webpack, yammer

Just wanted to report a bug to the yammer team.  It looks like Yammer started using webpack to build their yammer SDK script that they host on a CDN.  When we pulled that in, we ended up with what the webpack docs call "multiple webpack runtimes from different compilations" on our global window namespace, and the webpackJsonp function got overridden by Yammer. We were able to fix this by giving a unique name to the webpack json output function (see example in link below)

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputjsonpfunction (edited)